# Phrase for spinning your keys on your finger

Tags: phrase-requests

I see this "action" everywhere but I've never seen it written. If you're wondering what I'm talking about it's when someone "confidently spins their keychain thingy on their finger whilst walking over to their car". I see it in every movie with a guy that drives a car. It's so "everywhere", yet I have no idea how to write it in a way that's not awkward, like my title. So, is there a "phrase" for this action? The first thing I thought of was:

> He spun his keys on his finger as he walked over to his car

But it seems too awkward and clunky. I'm not sure if there is a dedicated phrase for this one very specific thing, but any other alternatives are welcome as the one I currently have is very bad.

Comment: couldn't find a source to back this up, but I commonly hear _he played with his keys_

Comment: @rosslh Does on think of someone spinning the keys on their finger when hearing that phrase? If so then I'll use it, but I can't say I envision it myself. But then again, I've never seen the phrase before.

Comment: "Fiddling with one's keys" includes all such random activities; there's no special term for individual ones.

Comment: Sounds perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: I’d go with “He twirled his keys on/around his finger”

Answer (score 4):

I like "twirling his keys on his finger"

Answer (score 2):

**He twiddled [with] his keys.**

> **twiddle** verb   to turn about or play with lightly or idly, especially with the fingers; twirl.

{[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/twiddle)}

Twiddling a pencil obviously involves rotation, and twiddling a set of keys cannot really involve anything other than spinning them.

Answer (score 1):

> He **[swung](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/swing)** the keys around his finger and into his palm.

using the idea of a [pivot](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pivot)/[fulcrum](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fulcrum) from definition 4 in above link.

Answer (score 0):

> He fiddled with his keys while walking to his car.

**fiddle with** (something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fiddle+with) idiom

> to play or tinker with something to manipulate something without a
>   clear sense of purpose

and/or

> He **played with** with his keys while walking to his car.

**play with** (something) [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+with) idiom

> 1. To amuse oneself with something.
> 2. To idly or distractedly toy with or manipulate something.

Answer (score 0):

He *whirled his keys around his finger* as he walked over to his car.